# YouTube Live Streaming API - LiveChatMessage - userBannedEvent not receiving

Tags: youtube-api

[`liveChatMessages` docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages) defines `userBannedEvent` as one of the message types, but response data contains only LiveChatMessages with type `textMessageEvent`.

The question is, can I get userBannedEvents from requests to YouTube API?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a currently known issue with no provided workaround as of the moment. This [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtubegaming/comments/4kzfm1/api_not_receiving_userbannedevent/?st=j3i31v8x&sh=ef8a7d2f) is from a year ago, but upon looking around, there doesn't seem to be any update so far. From the thread:

> Yes, this is a known issue. We don't send userBannedEvent, messageRetractedEvent or messageDeletedEvent through the API right now.